# How to call function every time collection updates from server?

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

For example, in **this** controller parties object autoupdates when another user changes Paries collection, but how do we catch this update and run some controller logic?

```
this.helpers({ parties: () => Parties.find({}) });
```

SPECIFIED QUESTION:
Recieved answers do not solve my problem as it's not server logic or any database manipulations that I need to perform upon update. Actually it's controller logic that I need to run.

In the following example I disable submit button if form is not changed. isFormChange function compares party with originalParty. I need to redefine originalParty value when party changes from server side. So how can I do this?

```
<form ng-submit="vm.updateParty()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.party.name">
  <input type="submit" ng-disabled="!vm.isFormChanged()" value="Submit">
</form>
```

directive controller:

```
function Ctrl($scope, $reactive) {
  let vm = this;
  $reactive(vm).attach($scope);

  vm.helpers({ party: () => Parties.findOne({_id: vm.partyId}) });
  let originalParty = angular.copy(vm.party);
  vm.isFormChanged = isFormChanged;
  vm.updateParty = updateParty;

  function isFormChanged() {
    return !angular.equals(vm.party, originalParty);
  }

  function updateParty() {
    Meteor.call('updateParty', vm.party._id, vm.party.name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [collection-hooks](https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks) package to run code before or after updates, upserts, inserts, and removes.

```
myCollection.after.update(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options){
  ...your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please check the SPECIFIED QUESTION.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your logic on the server, if you have your database functionality in [Meteor methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods).

Example:

```
Parties = new Mongo.Collection("parties");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    // This code only runs on the client
    Meteor.subscribe("parties");
    /* a helper or event can run the Meteor.call() */
    var partyData = {}; // get partyData
    Meteor.call("insertParty", partyData,
        // callback function
        function (error, result) {
            if (error) { console.log(error); };
        });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    // This code only runs on the server
    Meteor.publish("parties", function () {
        return Parties.find({});
    });
    Meteor.methods({
        insertParty: function (partyData) {
            // insert logic to run on partyData here
            Parties.insert(partyData);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please check the SPECIFIED QUESTION.